# does not execute useEffect() error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

hello friends I have a problem in an application in react JS that is driving me crazy and I don't know how to solve it, I am making a call with axios to obtain information which I have already tried with postman and the backend works perfectly the issue is that I don't know this executing the useEffect() where I am making that call to fill a useState and pass that object by props to a child component. below sent code and error . thank you very much for any help you can give me I'm starting with react

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Breadcrumb from '../../common/breadcrumb';

import InfoGeneralQueja from './components/InfoGeneralQueja'
import InfoCalidadQueja from './components/InfoCalidadQueja'
import InfoDirectorQueja from './components/InfoDirectorQueja'

import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";






const QuejaDetalle = () => {
    const [detalle, setDetalle] = useState([])
    //id params
    const { id } = useParams()
    console.log("ID: ", id)

    //User
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

    //end point
    const endpoint = 'http://localhost:5000/detalle/'

    //Data
    const getQuejaById = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(endpoint + id)
        .then(function (response) {
            setDetalle(JSON.stringify(response.data))
         }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
        
    }
    //Triggered
    useEffect(() => {getQuejaById()},[])
   



    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Breadcrumb title={`Detalles Evento`} parent="Quejas" />
            <div className="container-fluid"></div>
            <div className="row">
                <InfoGeneralQueja quejaData={detalle} />
                <InfoCalidadQueja quejaData={detalle} user={user} />
                <InfoDirectorQueja quejaData={detalle} user={user} />
            </div >
        </Fragment >
    )
}

export default QuejaDetalle



//////////////////// Error ///////////////////////////////

InfoGeneralQueja.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at InfoGeneralQueja (InfoGeneralQueja.js:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
InfoGeneralQueja @ InfoGeneralQueja.js:32
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17811
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19049
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js @ index.js:74
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <InfoGeneralQueja> component:

    at InfoGeneralQueja (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2509:24)
    at div
    at div
    at QuejaDetalle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4061:66)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143525:26)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at AppLayout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1132:66)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143624:24)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143549:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:142986:23)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:140426:20)
    at div
    at Root (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15107:51)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20118
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12318
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12339
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20736
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js @ index.js:74
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
InfoGeneralQueja.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at InfoGeneralQueja (InfoGeneralQueja.js:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

Comment: Your error isn't shown in your question. Can you add the error so we can try to help.

Comment: InfoGeneralQueja.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at InfoGeneralQueja (InfoGeneralQueja.js:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error's stack shows that you're calling `.toString()` in `<InfoGeneralQueja />` on an undefined value. You need to properly handle the `detalle` prop before it's populated by the effect.

Do not use `await` and `.then`. These do the same thing in purpose. It might cause problems like this one.

```
    const getQuejaById = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(endpoint + id)
        setDetalle(JSON.stringify(res.data)) 
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }       
    }
```

Also, you need to ensure that you're getting the data you want from the API.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer, I tried changing the call but I think the main problem is that the useEffect is not executed, in fact if I put a console.log inside the useEffect before the same api call function I don't see it either

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers, I was able to solve it by conditioning the rendering since it was actually rendering before making the API call

```
{detalle.length>0 && <InfoGeneralQueja detalle={detalle} />}
            {detalle.length>0 && <InfoCalidadQueja detalle={detalle} user={user} />}
            {detalle.length>0 &&  <InfoDirectorQueja detalle={detalle} user={user} />}
```